# A birthday greeting

Tags: friends, greetings, birthdays

What could be a nice birthday message for someone I haven't talked to in a while?

We were best friends at school, but, due to the course our lives took later (different colleges, less contact), we sort of drifted apart and haven't talked in a while. It's her birthday in a few days, and I'm not sure what would make for a sweet and short birthday wish; of course, it should be more than just a *Happy Birthday, hope you have a great day* - considering that she's been an important part of my life and saying just happy birthday is too cliché.

Comment: A good birthday greeting is something heartfelt and personal. Anything we suggest will be cliche for this reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't talked in a while, then "Happy birthday, hope you have a great day" is exactly the sort of message you want to send. You can tack a "How's life" or similar on the end if you want.

It's her birthday, and you two haven't spoken recently. Don't put more pressure on the interaction than there needs to be.